# Strange Javascript date discrepency

Tags: javascript, date

Can anyone explain the discrepancy in the output below?  My code is as follows:

```
function addDaysToDate( theDate, days ) {
    var thisDate = new Date( theDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000 );
    return new Date( thisDate );
}

var dt = new Date( '5/20/2014' ); 

for (i=0;i<6;i++)   {
    var dt = addDaysToDate( dt, 7 );
    console.log( dt + '---' + dt.getMonth() + '/' + dt.getDate() + '/' + dt.getYear() );
}
```

The output generated from that is:

```
 Tue May 27 00:00:00 PDT 2014---4/27/2014 
 Tue Jun 3 00:00:00 PDT 2014---5/3/2014 
 Tue Jun 10 00:00:00 PDT 2014---5/10/2014 
 Tue Jun 17 00:00:00 PDT 2014---5/17/2014 
 Tue Jun 24 00:00:00 PDT 2014---5/24/2014 
 Tue Jul 1 00:00:00 PDT 2014---6/1/2014
```

I have looked at this a number of times, and for the life of my I cannot rationalize why dt.getMonth() shows a month prior to the current month.  I have confirmed identical behavior on both Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number returned by getMonth is zero-based, so January is 0, February is 1, and so on until December which is 11. From the [MDN Documentation on Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> *month*
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

And:

> **Date.prototype.getMonth()**
>
> Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to local time.